# How do I interpret the orientation of the gradient when using imgradient in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gradient

I am finding the gradient of an image. For now I am simply using a 5 x 5 image. I am more interested in finding the direction of the gradient but I am not getting the results manually on paper as I get them using MATLAB function `imgradient`. Please refer to the following images to know more about the input images and the Sobel filter that is used here to find the gradient of an image. One of the 3 x 3 sobel operator used here is the one that I get using the function

```
f1 = fspecial('sobel');
```

and the other one is obtained by just transposing the `f1`.

Please note that I am trying to find the direction of only one pixel here that is rounded by red color.  Here in the first two cases my result matches with that i obtain using `imgradient` function but in the third case `imgradient` gives -135 degree whereas I am getting it to be -45. Please help me find the error.

[image: Case one and case two]

[image: Case three (Mismatch in results)]

Also please explain how to interpret the following gradient directions as shown in the follwing image.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calculations are correct but it is highly recommended that you **don't** use the `atan(y/x)` definition because this calculation is not cognizant of the quadrant that the angle of the gradient resides in.  Doing `atan(y/x)` with your components would falsely report the angle to be -45 degrees when that isn't correct.  You should use `atan2` instead.

Now the internals of `imgradient` are quite straight forward.  I'd like to point out that the angle reported by `imgradient` is assuming that the `y` coordinate is increasing from bottom to top.  In addition, `imgradient` should report the angle of orientation that is pointing to the greatest rate of change.  In the case of images, this points in the direction where we progress from dark pixels to light pixels.

First a call to `imgradientxy` is called and a call to `fspecial('sobel')` is made if you provide the `sobel` flag to `imgradient`.  In fact, this portion of `imgradientxy` is what is important to remember (starting at line 75: MATLAB R2015a):

```
case 'sobel'
    h = -fspecial('sobel'); %// Align mask correctly along the x- and y- axes
    Gx = imfilter(I,h','replicate'); %'
    if nargout > 1
        Gy = imfilter(I,h,'replicate');
    end
```

Notice that the **negative** of the output of `fspecial` is performed as well as the comment provided at that line.  This is to ensure that the mask to detect horizontal edges (i.e. `Gy`) is **y-down** (as it is commonly known in computer graphics).  Specifically, the origin of the image is at the top-left corner and not the bottom left.

This is a pictorial representation of how the coordinate system is laid out in `y`-down:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia - Rotation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)</sup>

As such, when finding the orientation there is an additional requirement to ensure that the angle of the orientation of the gradient is with respect to the **y-up** coordinate system which is what we're used to.  Therefore when you are finding the angle of orientation of the gradient, you need to **negate** the `y` coordinate before calculating the angle so that the angle is with respect to the standard convention instead.

Pursuing the definition of the gradient that you seek is the conventional system of the `y` coordinate increasing from bottom to top.  The negation is required and in fact if you examine the source code for `imgradient`, this is precisely what is being done at line 127 of the code (version R2015a):

```
Gdir = atan2(-Gy,Gx)*180/pi; %// Radians to degrees
```

You may be asking yourself why there is a need to negate the mask and again negate the `y` coordinate after to find the orientation.  The reason why is because the modified mask is required to properly capture the magnitude of the gradient and so we negate the mask once and find the gradient magnitude and then we negate the `y` coordinate so that we can find the angle with respect to the conventional coordinate system.

In your case, given that `Gx = 765` and `Gy = -765`, substituting these quantities into the above equation yields:

```
>> Gy = 765;
>> Gx = -765;
>> Gdir = atan2(-Gy,Gx)*180/pi

Gdir =

  -135
```

This makes sense because the gradient direction corresponds to the direction towards the greatest rate of change.  -135 degrees means that we're pointing to the south west which does make sense as we are progressing from dark pixels to light pixels.

Now if you consult your third example image, the angles reported by `imgradient` are indeed correct.  Simply draw a line from the dark area to the light area and see what angle it makes with the `x` axis where it is aligned with the columns increasing towards the right.  The first angle of +90 degrees makes sense as we are moving from bottom to top to follow the dark area and light.  This is a similar situation with the situation where the image is reversed.  The third situation is what we have seen before and the fourth situation is simply the third situation rotated by 180 degrees and so naturally the angle of orientation from dark to light is now +45 degrees as opposed to -135 degrees previously.

Comment: @NavdeepSony no problem at all :) I'm glad to have helped.  Good luck!

Comment: I am getting confused about Gdir. I think Gdir is the direction of maximum intensity change and the edge is always orthogonal to it. Am I right? When I use `gx=[-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1] and gy=[-1 -2 -1;0 0 0;1 2 1]` all my answers matches with imgradient but I am unable to interpret the results. For example for case 1: I am getting `Gdir = 90` which is a line that resides on y (y-down) and I think that is showing intensity change. Smilarly for case 2: `Gdir = -90`, showing intensity change upwards but in case 3: `Gdir = -135` which is the angle at which the edge is present. What's the problem?

Comment: @NavdeepSony I've investigated `imgradient` a little more.  I know now what's going on.  Doing `atan2(-Gy,Gx)` ensures that the angle is with respect to `y`-up.  I will have to change my post because in `imgradient` they do use those masks that you specified and those masks themselves are `y`-down.  Therefore, the angle of -135 now makes sense which makes the gradient point southwest and that does make sense with that direction pointing to the greatest rate of change (i.e. from black to white).  I'm going to update my post to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was what I thought! But I am still unable to understand why have this been done `h = -fspecial('sobel'); %// Align mask correctly along the x- and y- axes` . How do you know, it is `y-down?` Also if we use   `h = fspecial('sobel');` the is it ok to just use `Gdir = atan2(Gy,Gx)*180/pi` rathar than `Gdir = atan2(-Gy,Gx)*180/pi`

Comment: I simply examined the mask. That's how I figured out the direction. Also yes what you said makes sense. Good luck!

Comment: You mean to say because we move from negative to positive values (from first row to third row), we can say it is y-down? or is it something else.